# Como usar uma logo diferente caso a padrão não exista?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Gostaria de saber se existe uma solução para o seguinte problema,

se existir a imagem logo_empresa  considerar ela e aplicar ao css, caso não exista utilize a logo_default, dessa forma eu poderia controlar versões e meus usuarios poderiam costumizar a aplicação sem medo de substituir os arquivos e voltar ao default, há alguma solução em css ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A resposta do @renan sobre [multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds) poderia resolver
>   o meu problema, porém em carregamentos de imagens com fundo
>   transparente as imagens acabam se misturando.

Na resposta do SO: [Fallback image and timeout - External Content Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588854/fallback-image-and-timeout-external-content-javascript)

encontrei uma solução em javascript que resolve perfeitamente o problema, seria verificar se a imagem existe, e no `onerror()` dela colocar a outra mensagem.

**Exemplo:**

Javascript - jQuery:

```
function checkImage(imagemDefault, imagemEmpresa) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = imagemDefault;
  img.onload = function() {
    $('#logo').attr('src', imagemDefault);
  };
  img.onerror = function() {
    $('#logo').attr('src', imagemEmpresa);
  };

}

var imagemDefault = 'imagemDefault.png';
var imagemEmpresa = 'imagemEmpresa .png';

checkImage(imagemDefault, imagemEmpresa);
```

HTML:

```
<img id="logo" alt="" />
```

Exemplo funcionando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/6zh52gwr/1/)

Answer (score 6):

O único jeito que conheço é por **server-side**. **PHP**, por exemplo.

Você pode por meio do PHP verificar se a imagem *logo_empresa.png* existe no diretório. Se sim, mostra. Se não, mostra *logo_default.png*.

Use a função **file_exists** para isso.
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-exists.php

Mas daí você tem que fazer isso no HTML e fazer via Style na Tag HTML.

```
if(file_exists('img/imagem.png'))
   echo '<div style="background-image:url(<?php echo $var; ?>)"> Teste </div>';
else
   echo '<div style="background-image:url('imagem_padrao.png')"> Teste ';</div>
```

---

Por curiosidade eu fui pesquisar e encontrei esse artigo:
http://blog.thiagobelem.net/css-dinamico-inserindo-php-no-css/

Comment: Queria te dar dois likes, mas só posso um, infelizmente, um pela solução server-side e outro pelo artigo do Thiago Belém. Ele é muito bom! Outra coisa eu acrecentaria que a customizacao poderia ser feita usando COOKIES PHP, caso não seja necessário login do usuário ou SESSION PHP se ele tiver que fazer login.

Answer (score 6):

É possível fazer com [**multiple backgrounds**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/CSS/Multiple_backgrounds).

A propriedade **`background`** aceita múltiplos planos de fundo empilhados como se fossem camadas, ficando um sobre o outro.

Dá para aproveitar isto definindo a imagem que tem a possibilidade de falhar (não existir) como a primeira camada de background. Se houver outras imagens, você pode colocá-las em sequência mas deixando a última camada com a imagem *default* para ser usada caso todas as anteriores venham a falhar.

No caso da primeira não ser encontrada, a segunda será utilizada. Se você possuir várias imagens, será procurada em ordem sequencial a primeira que não falhe.

```css
.logo {
  width: 235px;
  height: 90px;
  background: url('imagemQueVaiFalhar.png'), 
              url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqk9d.png'); /* default */
}
```

```html
<div class='logo'></div>
```

É possível ter uma imagem em base64, pro caso da segunda imagem também ter sido excluída, talvez por acidente. Mas há [alguns fatores](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5258101/4056678) a serem considerados, principalmente em navegadores mais antigos. Ainda assim, segue um exemplo:

```css
.logo {
  width: 235px;
  height: 90px;
  
  background: url('imagemQueNuncaVaiExistir.jpg'),
              url('imagemQueSubstituiAPrimeira.jpg'),
              url('imagemColoqueiPorDefaultEOUsuarioApagou.png'),
              url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOsAAABdCAYAAABEmZG9AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAABLeSURBVHhe7Z15kBVVlofdNdQ/DEPD3dEZw7FbmTBCB40Z2y3cwqFjdMaVdgQJ/9AIpwMZpDW0tQ1xbEFABVllU0BlkUXZFGQrpNm3kR1kUdlKqoCidupMfVl5ss7Leq82iuJl1fkiTtR799y8me/m/eU59758WSeJ4ziJwMXqOAnBxeo4CcHF6jgJwcXqOAnBxeo4CcHF6jgJwcXqOAnBxeo4CcHF6jgJwcXqOAnBxeo4CSHxYi1bO1WKhjxR+aI4LHGclkmixVo6410peOWqwEqmvB6WOk7LJNFiLVs5UY682aZKsK//RsqWjws9jtPySHwaXDKzRxRdC/v9Xo7uWhV6HKdlkXixVuTvluJPno0EWzy2S6WCj4Rex2k5JEasFcUHw1c1Kd80TwrfuyMSbMncAaHHcVoOiRBrRcE+Kf74bimd9j8ZV33LFgyJxHrk3X+R8vWzQ4/jtAyyX6wlBZVp7u+lsMffBVY86qFAvDWoFHHx+JciwRYN7yAVv+4InY6TfLJerBWFv0rpvL9KYc+/rxbs6P+sTH1nhDWqKf9ptRR+9O+RYEumdg89jpN8EjNnLVv6sRT2bxsJtmjQ76RsxSeht5qy5eOl4I3fVgn2z/8opUs/Dz2Ok2wSI1YoXzdZikf+WyTYwt6VYlzwXo3Fp5Lp/xtF18K+7eTozhWhx3GSS6LECuU7FkrxuA7Vgq20kund5Gju5rBGZep8YJcUjXgmEmzxF51Fig+HXsdJJlkp1pK8HbInp6+UFx8KS1KpyN0kpdO7pgi2eHxHKd++MKxRKeoNs6Xw3X+NBFs656PQ4zjJJCvFun3SC7Km52/khw/byt6/DZaKNF/XVBQeCBaeinr9QyTYohEPVqbKk8IaIqU5QyOxcneTHC0LPY6TPLJOrEX7NwVCtbau/+9k/7KRaUVbtmyYFA24tVqw/f9ZypYMDr2V2e/o56V0/iAXqpN4sjKyHto6R3ZO7SZre/9Timi3jHq8UrQjpPTwnrBmFeXrp0jRyHaRYLHSOd2lomBvWMNxkk9WLzAd3DxLdn7dVdb2uiFVtGPaS+6KUVJWkBvWrEyL83dJ8bD7UgWb0zv0Ok7yyWqxKvkbZ8iOKZ1TBItt/byD5K78TMqL8qsqlhRIyYROgVC504n3jtNSSIRYq6iQ/A3TZMekP9YQ7baxneTAmnFSXnI4mJuW/q1/+lsSHSfBJEis1RzatkA2j3y4hmgpK/hpeVirZTJ8+HA56aSTpGPHjmFJ62Pp0qUyYMAAeeONNwLLy8uTBQsWBH2i1hLJGrFuW/y5LB7937Jx7iDZu2mBlBzJCz3pYWU47/8myfYJz0ViXdurjRzc9E1Y4/jx448/BnYiaO1ife6554LPb41zof2i1hLJmk+1dupfZU6//4hs3oDHZPm4l2XTvMGye91sOZy7PaxZk4ObZgVRle9nm4MTOSBas1gHDhwY9b01F2szUnG0XOYPap8i1nRWV+TNdMdTU3MiB0RrFmu7du2ivj/rrLOka9euQX8cPnzYxdqcFBzYJXs2zpMtOcNl5cTXK8X7h7SCVZvb/9HKyPun6si7f1vY0vHnRA6I1izWa665Jup7hGtxsTYxeXn5kdVFYd4vlRE0R7Z+/4msmvwXWTDkv9KKVm3ll6+FWzZsP43hRA6I1izWq666Kur7+Od3sTYxb775dmQNpejgXtm3ZZFsWzRaVk95S3KGdkwR6+b5Q8OaDd/P7t27pXPnznLdddcF6dXFF18st912m7zwwguyeXP1r3moc+edd0YDgtfYE088EdaoYs6cOfLUU0/JzTffLOeee27Q3q233hpsz74y0bdv3yBiXH755XLeeecFbb/22mtSVFQU1qhbrEOGDAm2e+SRR4L00DJ9+nR56KGHokFPpKIex6v07Nkz8Kvt378/9FTDMan/hhtukLKyqls5+cvqrH5ujH6kfvxYFi1alLIfVnPZN9uedtppcsEFFwT9umvXrqgu5dr3tK3bUqc+YuWzcE7ZB+dZj49j1j7+9ttvo3YxVp4t1GOc4Iufd+Ac2u05tqYiK8RakP+r5OfukZKi+j+VsLy0SPJ+WhusIq+c+GfZv3Vx6GmYWNeuXRucND3JN954YyRa3jNAPv3006BufcRKHfUzkBHDAw88EJw4ytjXypUrw9pVIGDbLkJlsOp7jkkvGrWJdejQoXLhhRcGIhw7dmxYWsXLL78ctZfOOG6YNWuWnHrqqVF5v379gnKloKAgGOzqZ3UWWOThOLU8bvTF+vXrg7rABcL6tX/i9uyzz9aoG7f6LDBxMeCiaetY45zTx9u2bZPLLrssKu/ePfVpIyNGjIh8nKdVq1Ifffvwww9H/ttvvz0sbRqyQqxzxw+SMT3+GNjnvbrI5IF/kZmf9pJ5Xw6WxTM+kzU5U2XTivmyc+Mq2bdrqxw6sE/KSjL/u4xM+0kHJwlBckW0UY8owQDgSqyRQ9GTkQ4GPYPCDkygDRZE2A4xWRAz5RyL3Y5BiM+2l0msX375pVx77bVy0UUXBaK1cLGxUSmTjRw5Mqivx4M9+uijQZkyderUlG0mTJgQlNttMC5K9iKI2SjMBcv60hl9mZubG9TlYqYXUAxx68WS81abWOnHO+64I8Wfzp588kk5evSoPP7441EZmYjlmWeeSdnm/fffDz0ie/bskSuuuCLyvfLKK6GnacgKsc745L1IrA2xsX26ypTBb8q3o/tIWWlJ2Fr9xbphwwY588wza5yQutCTkYlMqS4DVSOmRsqJEycG70l9023HNrY8nViJPLfccoucffbZKYMHSNvswgzRgBsKaJOU2UZwLhbsr3fv3lEZkfqHH34IWxN56aWXIl/btm3l4MGDNSIf7dMOFhcRPohvw3FwPKSqn332WZCaxrHRN+6vTayk4dZHtCajIr2+5557UnxMFT788MPoPefll19+CdrZsWOHXH311Sn1iaTK119/neLjfVOSFWKdN2GQfDWku4z74E9pRVmXff7ei2FLVWTaT5x169YFnXrvvfdKeXl5WFo3ejIaA3NXtmWwAqLj/dtv150FQFysRB2Nam+99VZQZkFo+NTig7xHjx4p/jVr1gQD+dJLL43KPvqo6of7R44cCQSq5a+++mpQTvahZfFVWmCaEPfHxdqnT5+gvDYaK1YrSCLxvn3Vt6IuWbIkpd0XX3xRVqxYIeecc05UNmXKlKAumYeWqZ1//vmyevXqwM8xafn1118v3FnVlGSFWC1EyIL8XNn/8zbZtWmNbFqZI2sXTpclM7+Q+RM/DqIo0ZSoqmKdNDD1xNVnP4qeKK746RZT0qEnpD6wwEAaphYXq85Vv//+++B9XVixErlYIOE9KWY6vvvuu8CvxtzNgjitf9q0aUF5hw4dorLHHnssKMOnZaTV+hlsCszCGuXW7F1HRG+gXMswFnbqorFibdOmTVT+/PPPh6XVaB9ipMKg5wnTffHZtMzOz8kIQM8lFp+mNAVZJ9aGUFpSFMxfD+eliqwh+yEVsqkg8ywGFBGA9MmuBitaNx2knUQJTmZ8zmaNwQo6AEmx6oMVq0YsnY+SUschpcSnxgXDwnvrp3346quvojLa50JmF89YZFKsiOoy2oL4nFX7ozYaK1Y7141vB1ZkvAayFC1DzJxXPZ+0Z4+fyM1qt93PuHFN/0/SskKshw4dPmazZNpPJkhXWGBi5ZYrKoPCrgbrAFb0hKSDNvCxKMTciMFhTQecDk7mkLyPf7WRCR2UOnC4qDDP4jXzq3jqxaDBpxZfvdy+fXuKX1d/idp29ZToQfv63qatDRErBs0pVrvo061bt7C0mgcffDDysxAF9vgYAyzS6Xtd49DoGvczdup7PhtCVojVljfWLJnKGwKdrauoCIPBq+hJiUMqRzkLOplOll7FdXDqKuXy5fX7tZAdlAwW3Y+maFwgLHWJgszB+u2FSVevMStc+sROGewCFtlIfWhOsdqUNV16atNgO+e2+7Ov9as8G32tn0h7PHCx1oFGShZdFD0pcfTk1TZg42LVVNaKpDZ0UCIeu0rMa43SduDv3LkzKFNDgBYWtqzfbst3rqecckqKH2vfvn1YowoEoD4yk3ToTQfK8RarvbjqOcRuuummlCnHwoULU75XtZG3S5cuUbnalVdeKVu3bg38bHvGGWfUqMNq+vEgK8Tau/cHx2yWTPtJR7qvSywqJvv9p4oifnfKO++8E5THBaEwgHTA6eDUOSVzQDvALHag66BMFyF69eoV+O6++27ZsmVLWJo6JyNL4E4hPg9/9bNg9ntQ5f7774/8asOGDQu9VWhGocbcVtNx/pIysx8ryKYWq04F1Lhg0iZz8riQES8LbczL7UISZo+D766tD3v66adDbxX33Xdfiv/000+XxYurb9BpSrJCrE1NfffDfI6UjhQyvhLMoOUk4yeKWfSrAAalTXc50ZSzYMVgtJBu2iu8HRTaHv64WLjziAUvvajUJtYDBw4E8yn8bKdMmjSp1sUu7OSTT5ZRo0aFW1SjFwA1jiXdLXQ2uqrZhTuMvkQg0NRi5TzYC4+tR7/YeWkmi/fp3r17gxtNbB3636IXaLW77ror9DQ9rVqspLb2yoooiUKYDgwGWHwgsYJMOX4WE6irqFgw5nK0xV/qIxid+9k27Vc6DDjmTQhXj4G/Kv7axAqTJ08ORILZ1WEGlR5z3CjPlLrz1c4ll1wS1eU71XQQQe3cMJ2RpejFranFCiwS2jZtPe7xtdvHjWNPt/LfqVOnqA7bx1fTGQvcWKN16jtnbwwnTKz2lzFNbXY/9YHvWBEHJwxBMdB5TeSMnxyFk8/gU3FbWDll0YLVU8RMNKJ92mIbTjon2UJEJV1EqGyHaGmXk2+jN9kA22dKtYGoSp34nVkcMwtQfDaOi7+8r0so7Es/Z/zG9jgsvpApqDC4OPGedN+CWLVNLJ6JpMP2dzzCKaTkXMjS1aMfWVegjznH9DOvuZBlmoKQCWhbmfqczEzr1NU/x8IJE2tzmeO0FFysjpMQmlWsH3zQr9nNcVoKzSpWx3Eaj4vVcRKCi9VxEoKL1XESgov1OFNYWBjc+meNJw805Mfu2QqPXOHuqI0bN4YlzvHExXqc4bk83BDAj8uxnJyc4LlF3F106NCxP5Scn7hxQWhu2CePLeE2TT6PPvrEOX64WI8ziDXdj8L5Sdzs2bPDd42HttlHc0NU1Zv1ueg05SM3nfS4WCspKSkJBl/8ljPKiRwVFRXBwMzPr35oOGksZfhqI5NYNeIeC0Q3ohq3MWp05bji4sXHzexxKOf42Ua3B+ra90Cb8dQ9U78pxcXFQVstIeXPBlq9WLlRfcyYMUFK98UXX6T8tIwByvN3v/nmm8AQxsyZMwNxIDQepIWfB69lIpNYeWID8z2FNml//PjxUXqpcEw8/2j+/PlBWxpNly1bFh07rwEB6Y+jFbbn+BXaZhuOHeM+ZeufO3dujc9E39h7lOk3+oDjivcbQue3sLRJf3GM1u80jlYtVq76DFaNmDy9D8FoVEEQDHzmhUAUYpAz+HTgqqAzRQ/8CJC/agx0ttEftLN/2uQnWcBfBKltMtDtcbBvjegqXKU+YkVIHAMQFblZvSFi1X7TfiLDwK/vaZunBipE2EzR16k/rVqsDEgWfCxEGf2lDSIgelgh8usQIpyFCKlCi0Mb/E5UIyJGNOIRoSo4oiwRyIJ4dB6I2GwUtjRGrHwmnW8C8+eGiBVf/DE0bKP9xnHzY3A7bXCOnVYtVkTCYGegWvv5558DPxGEQWphoMYfG8o2PD4lHenaiMNxxNvkvaaOcbFZGiNW/PYCxFcv1l+XWOvqNy5CbM8FSKcOvgB17LRqsfJE/niUtDSXWImy8ZVhIr6mvQ0RKyknYuSvQvt2+7oiK79v1TQZSGFpU8VaV7/F4XNwnJpJOI2jVYuVNA0h2ZVPVjeV5hIrdZiz6nEQHZnn6vvaxErUUlErbKuRkQhKSmq3t3NWnYdbP6k+ZRp9eYKCFWtd/cZ3rtaXbjrhNJxWLVYg6iAUognRjUGqUam5xAosyLBow4O8EJt9xEhtYtVVZF0NBrZlnszCEW0haLs982uOidVs/vK5rV8X2vCpkK1YobZ+I01mW/bL/Jxj4DM4x0arFysQBbj6x783JRIwcC1EPZtiAttnihrUjz+MLRNELI7DigJoH9Fngn3E/doW25LG2kgHbIOfeswn4xcD9Wu7HFM8jc3Ub0AfcVGo7bidhuFidYIV8PgzoZzsw8XaCmG+ygIRC0Ws/JJ+x6O5k324WFshpKz8h2/mycw946m+k524WB0nIbhYHSchuFgdJyG4WB0nIbhYHSchuFgdJyG4WB0nIbhYHSchuFgdJyG4WB0nIbhYHSchuFgdJyG4WB0nIbhYHSchuFgdJyG4WB0nIbhYHSchuFgdJyG4WB0nIbhYHScRiPw/Oe5MNKcoAIQAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
}
```

```html
<div class='logo'></div>
```

Comment: +1, mas isso faz dois requests HTTP (e baixa os dois logos) mesmo que o logo customizado *esteja* disponível e *seja* válido.

Comment: @re22 o fato da sobreposição afetaria imagens com o fundo transparente que é um padrão que trabalhamos haveria uma forma de ao existir a primeira imagem a segunda desaparecer ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/filadown/oavz3dhw/

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Não encontrei nada a respeito, creio que não. Com [**Javascript**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1588854) é possível, mas como sua duvida foi específica em CSS, essa é uma forma de fazer.

Comment: @re22 testar o metodo postado por Craig Stuntz e verificar se ele resolve o meu problema, te dou um feedback